# Как прочесть символ конца строки '\n' в файле?

Tags: c++

Решил прочесть из текстового файла матрицу и определить количество строк и столбцов.

Исхожу из соображений, что данные, записанные в текстовый файл, представляют собой некий одномерный массив, разделенный символами конца строк '\n'.

Построчный анализ в окне Debug показывает, что реализованный код читает все символы, а символ конца строки пропускает, перескакивая на следующую строку.

Никак не могу понять где ошибка. Помогите!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

int main(){

int i = 0; // индекс элементов строки ФАЙЛА

int row_size = 0; // количество строк матрицы

int column_size = 0; // количество столбцов матрицы

char* buffer; // указатель на адрес, по которому должны временно размещаться числа, полученные из строки файла

ifstream input_data("The_Matrix.txt");

if(!input_data.is_open()){

    cout << "Cant open file" << endl;

}else{

    while(input_data>>buffer){

            if(*buffer=='\n'){

                column_size=i;

                i = 0;

                row_size++;

            }

        i++;

    }
}

cout << row_size << " ";

cout << column_size << endl;

input_data.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer` используется неинициализированным, *символ конца строки пропускает* - читайте про работу оператора >>

Comment: После чтения по неинициализированному адресу больше разбирать нечего - UB, возможно **всё**...

Comment: В строке `char * buffer;` объявлена переменная `buffer`. которая *должна* содержать указатель на `char`, но содержит случайное значение.

Comment: Если Вам нужен один символ, то это `char`, а не `char*`. И сравнение будет выглядеть `buffer == '\n'`

Comment: Выход есть - читайте про работу оператора >>, тогда вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос разрешился путем использования метода get(). Именно он помогает **не упустить символ конца строки ФАЙЛА**.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

int main(){

int i = 0; // индекс строки ФАЙЛА

int row_size = 0; // количество строк матрицы

int column_size = 0; // количество столбцов матрицы

char buffer;

float input_variable;

ifstream input_data("The_Matrix.txt");

if(!input_data.is_open()){

    cout << "Cant open file" << endl;

}else{

    while(input_data>>input_variable){ // считываем ЧИСЛА из потока

        i++; // увеличивается только, когда из потока получено ЧИСЛО, НЕ СИМВОЛ

        input_data.get(buffer); // записываем СИМВОЛЫ из файла в проверочный буфер

        if(buffer=='\n'){ //проверка входного СИМВОЛА на наличие символа конца СТРОКИ ФАЙЛА

            column_size=i; // фикcируем количество ЧИСЕЛ в строке ФАЙЛА, это и будет количество СТОЛБЦОВ МАТРИЦЫ

            i = 0; // обнуляем счетчик количества чисел в СТРОКЕ ФАЙЛА

            row_size++; // запускаем счетчик количества символов конца строки '\n' ФАЙЛА. Это и будет количество СТРОК МАТРИЦЫ

        }

    }
}

cout << "Row number is "<<row_size + 1 << endl;

cout << "Column number is " << column_size << endl;

input_data.close();

return 0;
}
```

Программа очень сырая и пока не содержит защиты от неправильного написания матрицы в самом файле, но главное ответ на поставленный вопрос получен! :-)